# C++ function specialization behaves different for plain types and classes

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

i have this piece of code (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee05a00fc8ab5057):

```
    #include <type_traits>

    struct unregistered;
    unregistered register_type(...);
    template<class T>
    constexpr bool is_registered = !std::is_same_v<unregistered, decltype(register_type(std::declval<T>()))>;

    template<class T>
    struct test_registration
    {
        static_assert(is_registered<T>, "Type is not registered!");
    };

    struct foo{};
    struct bar{};

    void register_type(int);
    void register_type(char);
    void register_type(void*);
    void register_type(foo);
    void register_type(foo*);

    #include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(test_registration<foo>).name()) << "\n";
        std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(test_registration<foo*>).name()) << "\n";

        std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(test_registration<int>).name()) << "\n";
        std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(test_registration<char>).name()) << "\n";
        std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(test_registration<void*>).name()) << "\n";

        std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(test_registration<long>).name()) << "\n";
        std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(test_registration<bar>).name()) << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

The compiler generates errors for the calls using `int`, `char`, `void*`, `long` and `bar`.
I expect the errors for `long` and `bar`.

What I do not understand is:

1. Why are `int`, `char`, and `foo` treated differently?
2. Why are `void*`, and `foo*` treated differently? (both are ptrs)

I assume the reason has to do with `foo` beeing class type and `int` and `char` beeing plain types.
I would like to know the reason. Is it a compiler bug or is there some passage in the standard explaining this behaviour?

What I am asking is not how I can fix this problem (see link to coliru for a fix).
What I want to know is why it is behaving like this.

Comment: The fix is simple, you reorder the `register_type` declarations to before `is_registered`, the explanation is not. But this isn't a bug, this is fully compliant.

Comment: ... it's even less simple if you also want to know why the specializations (in your link) *do work* as expected.

Comment: @PasserBy: As I stated, I want to know why it is necessary to do the reordering for plain types but not for `foo` and `foo*`.
@StoryTeller: If you mean why `foo` and `foo*` are working, I am asking for an explanation for this.